# how can I force launchpad build my package with g++ 4.7 or newer

Tags: c++, gcc, launchpad

I have a c++11 source code that I need to package using launchpad for ubuntu 12.04, which contains only old 4.6 gcc.

I changed the control file so that it contains:

```
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9), g++ (>= 4.7.0), libqt4-dbus, libqt4-dev, libqt4-network, libqt4-opengl, libqt4-webkit, libqtwebkit-dev, libqtgui4, libqtcore4, libqt4-xml, qt4-dev-tools, qt4-qmake, python3-dev
```

However, launchpad totaly ignore that. It doesn't even say there is no gcc 4.7 on system, it just run ./configure (which apparently fail, slapping launchpad for trying to build with g++ 4.6).

What is a proper way to enforce g++ 4.7 or newer? I added dependency ppa which contains gcc-4.7 and gcc-4.8 but I just don't know how to tell launchpad to install that.

Comment: It may be that Launchpad is actually installing the `g++` package that is from the dependency PPA you specified, and so is meeting the requirements. However, the `g++` binary itself is symlinked to `g++-4.6` and isn't changed to use `g++-4.7`. The proper solution would be, I think, to define the `CC` and `CXX` environment variables to specify the compiler to use. Can you try this method? Also, you aren't cheating Launchpad; Launchpad is doing what you told it to do.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that this works despite it's a nasty hack:

replace g++ with g++-4.7

```
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9), g++-4.7, libqt4-dbus, libqt4-dev, libqt4-network, libqt4-opengl, libqt4-webkit, libqtwebkit-dev, libqtgui4, libqtcore4, libqt4-xml, qt4-dev-tools, qt4-qmake, python3-dev
```

This will fail on all systems with g++ newer than 4.7 but it will cheat the launchpad